# pass two of pk into url

Tags: python, django

If the 'school year' value is changed, 404 does not appear.
I want data to be displayed only when both 'school_year' and 'pk' have the right values in url.

for example
If you have data that (School_Year = 2020, pk = 33)
when you enter url https://190.0.1/190/190/33 and https://190.0.1/190/whatthell/33
Both are the same results.

However, I would like to display the result only when both values are correct.

i really dont know if i explained correctly, thanks.

view.py

```
class StudentDetail(DetailView,FormView):
        model = Student
        template_name = 'student/member.html'
        context_object_name = 'student'
        form_class = AddConsultation
    
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['pk'] = Student.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
            return context
```

url.py

```
path('student/<school_year>/<pk>/', views.StudentDetail.as_view(), name='student_detail'),
```

html link

```
<a href='{% url 'student_detail' student.school_year student.pk %}'>
```

models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    school_year = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=SCHOOL_YEAR_CHOICES,
        default='2021N',
        verbose_name='school year'
    )
    ... etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove `get_context_data` and override `get_object` using `get_object_or_404`:

```
class StudentDetail(DetailView, FormClass):
    model = Student
    template_name = 'student/member.html'
    context_object_name = 'student'
    form_class = AddConsultation

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(Student, pk=self.kwargs['pk'], school_year=self.kwargs['school_year'])
```

Other solution may be:

```
class StudentDetail(DetailView, FormClass):
    model = Student
    template_name = 'student/member.html'
    context_object_name = 'student'
    form_class = AddConsultation
    slug_field = 'school_year'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'school_year'
    query_pk_and_slug = True
```

but I find the first one less magic :)

Comment: cheers! it works. what is diffrent between get_context_data  and get_object?

Comment: get_object is used to populate object variable in the template, get_context_data is used to add more to template context